# Java Game Dev: How to center the view of two characters in a platformer?

Tags: java

So im working on this game and right now I have two characters in the game and the problem is that if one character lags behind he gets left of screen. It works when I have one character on screen with the line of code

```
centerViewportOnGameObject(sonic, 0.0, 0.0, gameEngine.screenWidth/2.0,
       gameEngine.screenHeight/2.0);"
```

But when I add a second character on character takes priority and is left off screen. Help on how to solve this would be nice thank you.

Here is the code for the gamelayer:

```
package tutorials.platformTutorial;

import game.assets.*; import game.engine.*;
import game.physics.*; import game.geometry.*;


public class PlatformLayer extends CollisionSpace {

    public static final double GRAVITY_STRENGTH = 800.0;

    public PlatformLayer( GameEngine gameEngine ) {
        super( "PlatformLayer", gameEngine );

        width = 10000;
        height = gameEngine.screenHeight;

        setGravity(0, GRAVITY_STRENGTH );

        addGameObjectCollection( "Platforms" );
        addGameObjectCollection( "Balls" );

        createBackground();
        createPlatforms();
        createCharacter();
        createCharacter2();

    }

    private void createBackground() {
        GameLayer backgroundLayer = 
                new GameLayer( "BackgroundLayer", this.gameEngine );
        backgroundLayer.width = gameEngine.screenWidth;
        backgroundLayer.height = gameEngine.screenHeight;

        GameObject background = new GameObject( backgroundLayer );
        background.setName("Background");
        background.setPosition( backgroundLayer.width/2, backgroundLayer.height/2 );

        ImageAssetRibbon backgroundAsset = (ImageAssetRibbon)assetManager.retrieveGraphicalAsset("Background");
        background.setRealisation(backgroundAsset);
        background.setGeometry( new Box( 0, 0, 1024, 768));

        backgroundLayer.addGameObject(background);
        gameEngine.addGameLayer(backgroundLayer);

        setDrawOrder(backgroundLayer.getDrawOrder() + 1);

    }

    private void createPlatforms() {
        double groundOffset = 0;
        while( groundOffset < this.width ) {
            createPlatform( groundOffset, this.height - assetManager.retrieveGraphicalAssetArchetype
                    ("Platform").height );
            groundOffset += assetManager.retrieveGraphicalAssetArchetype("Platform").width;

      }

        for( int idx = 0; idx < 8; idx++ )
            createPlatform( 300+150 * idx, this.height-50*(idx+1) );
        for( int idx = 0; idx < 8; idx++ )
            createPlatform( 2500-150 * idx, this.height-50*(idx+1) );
        for( int idx = 0; idx < 5; idx++ )
            createPlatform( 3500-400 * idx, this.height-50*(idx+1) );
        for( int idx = 0; idx < 10; idx++ )
            createPlatform( 4500+150 * idx, this.height-50*(idx+1) );
        for( int idx = 0; idx < 12; idx++ )
            createPlatform( 6000, this.height-50*(idx+1) );
        for( int idx = 0; idx < 12; idx++ )
            createPlatform( 7200, this.height-50*(idx+1) );
    }

    private void createPlatform( double x, double y ) {
        Body platform = new Body( this );
        platform.setRealisationAndGeometry("Platform");
        platform.setPosition(x, y);
        platform.setMass( Double.MAX_VALUE );

        addGameObject( platform, "Platforms" );

    }

    private void createCharacter() {
        SonicSprite sonic = new SonicSprite( this );
        sonic.setPosition( 0, gameEngine.screenHeight - sonic.height - 200 );
        addGameObject( sonic );
    }

    private void createCharacter2() {
        SonicSprite2 sonic2 = new SonicSprite2( this );
        sonic2.setPosition(0, gameEngine.screenHeight - sonic2.height - 200);
        addGameObject( sonic2 );
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        super.update();

        updateViewPort();
        updateGameObjects();

    }

    private void updateViewPort() {
        GameObject sonic = getGameObject( "Sonic");
        GameObject sonic2 = getGameObject( "Sonic2");




        centerViewportOnGameObject(sonic, 0.0, 0.0, gameEngine.screenWidth/2.0, gameEngine.screenHeight/2.0);
        centerViewportOnGameObject(sonic2, 0.0, 0.0, gameEngine.screenWidth/2.0, gameEngine.screenHeight/2.0);

        GameObject background = gameEngine.getGameObjectFromLayer("Background", "BackgroundLayer");
        ((ImageAssetRibbon)background.getRealisation(0)).setViewPort((int)viewPortLayerX, 0 );
        background.getRealisation(0).update();

    }

  private void updateGameObjects() {
      GameObject sonic = getGameObject( "Sonic" );
      sonic.update();
      GameObject sonic2 = getGameObject( "Sonic2" );
      sonic2.update();

      GameObjectUtilities.reboundIfGameLayerExited(sonic);
      GameObjectUtilities.reboundIfGameLayerExited(sonic2);


  }
```

}

Comment: You could create a bounding box between the players (which represents the area that is between them) and center the screen around it.  You could also limit the movement to prevent either character from leaving the screen, so the bounding box can only ever be the width/height of the playable area....as an idea

Comment: ill edit to show you the code.

Comment: there that should help

Comment: hello? have any ideas now that i have added the code?